# Local notification when tapped open the android app

Tags: android, android-notifications

I use this code to create a local notification and show it after 30 seconds using AlarmManager.

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( context, default_notification_channel_id ) ;
    String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    builder.setContentTitle( "Check new words for "+currentDate ) ;
    builder.setContentText("30 seconds delay") ;
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round ) ;
    builder.setAutoCancel( true ) ;
    builder.setChannelId( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ) ;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( context, AlarmReceiver. class ) ;
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver. NOTIFICATION_ID , 1 ) ;
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver. NOTIFICATION , builder.build()) ;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent. getBroadcast ( context, 6977 , notificationIntent , PendingIntent. FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ) ;
    long futureInMillis = SystemClock. elapsedRealtime () + 30000 ;

    assert alarmManager != null;


    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP , futureInMillis , 1000*10,pendingIntent1);
```

This is the code from the AlarmReceiver

```
import static com.example.couponnectcom.MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID;
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "hello" ;
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "aha" ;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
    
  
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo myProcess = new ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo();
        ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(myProcess);
        Boolean isInBackground;
        isInBackground = myProcess.importance != ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND;
        if(isInBackground) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "12. APPLICATION BACKGROUND RUN NOTIFICATION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context. NOTIFICATION_SERVICE ) ;
            Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra( NOTIFICATION ) ;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION. SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES. O ) {
                int importance = NotificationManager. IMPORTANCE_HIGH ;
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID , "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME" , importance) ;
                assert notificationManager != null;
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel) ;
            }
            int id = intent.getIntExtra( NOTIFICATION_ID , 0 ) ;
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.notify(id , notification) ;
        }
        

    }
}
```

When the user taps on the notification i want my Android app to open...how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `PendingIntent`. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) for more information.

For explicit instructions on how to start an Activity from a Notification with a PendingIntent see [this article.](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation)

```java
PendingIntent openActivityIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 
                              0, 
                              new Intent(context, YourActivity.class), 
                              0);
builder.setContentIntent(openActivityIntent);
```

Comment: Ok but how i am gonna open my app if its closed or bring it to foreground if its in background?

Comment: All the information that you need is in the documentation.

Comment: So i have to implement a Regular Activity?

Comment: No. Does not do anything. Show me with my code if you please.

Comment: What is the name of the activity you want to start?

Comment: Good question. I changed the name of the class PendingIntent pendingIntent =
              PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class),0); and it worked. So for everyone trying and not working change the name of the class to the name of the acivity class you have in your project. I am accepting your answer as correct since the problem solved.